# How to Merge Multiple Panda's DataFrames into an Array for each Column Value Based on Another Column Value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have several Panda's Dataframes that I would like to merge together. When I merge them I would like the values that have the same columns to become an array of values.

For example, I would like to merge two data frames together if they have the same value in a specified column. When they are merged the data becomes an array of values.

```
  df1 = 
        A   Value
    0   x   0
    1   y   0


  df2 = 
        A   Value
    0   x   1
    1   y   1
    2   z   1


  After Combining:
  df =
        A   Number_Value 
    0   x   [0, 1]       
    1   y   [0, 1]       
    2   z   [, 1]
```

I do not believe the `merge()` or `concat()` call would be appropriate. I thought calling .to_numpy() would be able to do this, if I were to convert each value in each row to an array, but that does not seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with aggregate `list`:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby('A', as_index=False).agg(list)
print (df)
   A   Value
0  x  [0, 1]
1  y  [0, 1]
2  z     [1]
```

Test DataFrames without `A` column:

```
L = [df1, df2]
print ([x for x in L if 'A' not in x.columns])
```

EDIT: For add `''` for empty values add it to `fill_value` parameter:

```
L = [df1, df2]

df = pd.concat(L, keys=range(len(L))).reset_index(level=1, drop=True).set_index('A', append=True)
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df.index.levels)
df = df.reindex(mux, fill_value='').groupby('A').agg(list).reset_index()

print (df)

   A   Value
0  x  [0, 1]
1  y  [0, 1]
2  z   [, 1]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, using this causes a KeyError, with 'A' being the Key. I have checked and every df has this column.

Comment: @questioner1234 - Can you test like edited answer?

Comment: It printed both dfs. It seems like 'A' is in its own separate row. I messed up here on this statement df_list[i] = df_list[i].groupby(df_list[i]['Function']).mean() from an earlier part of my code. I will mark your answer as the correct one. It appears the error is on my end

Comment: do you know if there is a simple way to turn this sort of output into one long list when I am looping through and combining the dfs? Currently for example: `[[[[[0.0, 0.0]]]]]` or it could be like this `[[[[3, 2], 2], 3], 6]` and I need it in this sort of format: `[0.0, 0.0, , , ]` Where the empty commas denote no matching column to concatenate it on. Thank you

Comment: @questioner1234 - It is more complicated, do you need empty spaces? like `[0.0, 0.0, '','' ,'' ]` ?

Comment: Preferably I would put zeroes there

Comment: @questioner1234 - add to answer, solution working if unique values in `A` per each DataFrame.